# Работа с определённой частью массива

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Есть массив с подмассивами в отдельном php-файле:

```
array (

$subarray1 = array (
   name=>aaa
   pic=>aaa
)

$subarray2 = array (
   name=>bbb
   pic=>bbb
)

)
```

Он парсится через include в отдельной php-странице
Я хочу сделать генерацию страницы, где при запросе из адресной строки, брался определённый подмассив, и php работал только с ним. То есть, если в адресную строку вводится

```
site/page.php?arrayname=subarray2
```

То в подставленные [name] и [pic] должны выводиться bbb
Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

массив в отдельном файле `inc.php`

```
<?php
return [
   'key1' => [
       'name' => '...',
       'pic' => '....',
   ],
   'key2' => [
       ...  
   ],
];
```

Вызывающий файл `index.php`

```
<?php
$data = include 'inc.php';

$key = $_GET['key'] ?? 'default';
$value = $data[$key] ?? current($data);
print_r($value);
```

При вызове `index.php?key=key1` в `$value` получим искомый массив. Если параметр `key` не передан, то можем назначить какой-то ключ по умолчанию, в данном случае `default`. Если переданный ключ отсутствует в подключаемом массиве, то можем взять первый, или отдать 404, ошибку.

Comment: А как тот самый default увести в 404 страницу?

Comment: @LatexMoose как-то так `if (!array_key_exists($data, $key)) { http_status_code(404}; exit; }`

Comment: Только в !array_key_exists сначала идёт $key, а затем $data